# Regex replace specific word inside curly brace

Tags: javascript, regex

```
Hello

{#if wordToReplace}
 World
{/if}

{#each wordToReplace as item}
{item.name}
{/item}
```

I would like to replace the "wordToReplace" to "REPLACED" (inside curly brace) so it become

```
Hello

{#if REPLACED}
 World
{/if}

{#each REPLACED as item}
{item.name}
{/item}
```

How could I do that with regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try searching on the regex pattern:

```
\{(.*?)\bwordToReplace\b(.*?)\}
```

and then replace with:

```
{$1 REPLACED $2}
```

```js
var input = "Hello\n\n{#if wordToReplace}\n World\n{/if}\n\n{#each wordToReplace as item}\n{item.name}\n{/item}";
var output = input.replace(/\{(.*?)\bwordToReplace\b(.*?)\}/g, "{$1REPLACED$2}");
console.log(input);
console.log(output);
```

The regex pattern used here just blankets all content on either side of the search term in two separate capture groups, and then reuses those same capture groups in the replacement.